# slow performance ai objective-c iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, artificial-intelligence

I already have my brain broken with ai for tic-tac-toe type board game.
Problem is slow ai performance on high levels (even low levels has not so quick).

AI uses recursive method to find best move from number of available moves.

Here is some code:

```
@impelementation AIClass

- (NSMutableArray *)findLegalMoves
{
   // Here is code that finds available legal moves
   // Loop over board array
}

- (float)scoreOpponentsTurn:(float)min max:(float)max depth:(int)depth
{
   moveType t; // moveType is struct defined in .h file 
               // typedef struct { int x, y; } moveType
   NSMutableArray *moves = [self findLegalMoves];
   for ( NSValue *val in moves ) {
      [val getValue:&it]
      float score = [self scoreMove:it min:min max:max depth:depth];
      if ( score > min ) {
         min = score; 
      }
      if ( score > max ) { 
         min = 1000000000;
      }
   }
   return min;
}

- (float)scoreMove:(moveType)m min:(float)min max:(float)max depth:(int)depth
{
   NSMutableArray *changes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSMutableArray *undo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   float score;
   [self.board evaluateChangesOnCol:m.x Row:m.y];
   if ( [self.board checkForWin:&changes undo:&undo] ) {
       score = 1000000000 + [self calcH]; //calcH - evals heuristic like sum of params
   } else if ( depth > 0 ) { 
       score = - [self scoreOpponentsTurn:-1000000000 max:-min depth:depth - 1];
   } else {
       score = [self calcH]; 
   }
   [self.board applyChanges:undo];
}

- (moveType)findBestMove
{
   NSMutableArray *legalMoves = [self findLegalMoves];
   NSMutableArray *bestMoves = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   int min = -1000000000;
   int max = 1000000000;
   moveType move;
   for ( NSValue *moveIt in legalMoves ) {
      [moveIt getValue:&move];
      float score = [self scoreMove:move min:min max:max depth:depth];
      // Here i have some conditions to decide current move is best or not
   }
   // and pick random move from best moves and assign it to move variable
   return move;
}    

@end
```

And if number of legal moves like 3 and more (over recursive search it grows) this algorithm 
works very slow.

It's my first objective-c experience. 
Here is my guesses about how to improve performance:

1. Remove recursion (but I don't see another solution)
2. Use multithreading (how?)
3. May be use some ai library?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Just a tip: Try to run your game with "Profile" (Command+I) and pick the Time Profiler instrument. When running the game it will tell you which parts of your app takes the most amount of time to process. This will help you find areas to improve in your code.

Comment: How big is the board? Are you using the classic 3x3?

Comment: Board 15x15. And not all cells are legal at time. Player can put cap only next to other caps on board

Comment: I tried use Time Profiler and I like it, found that it may useful tool, but not for me at the moment, cause I just learning) But anyway thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing away recursion in an algorithm that is a natural fit for recursion is not a good idea. Rather, you need to [*memoize*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) your recursive solution. This common trick speeds up recursive solutions with common subproblems by orders of magnitude.

Consider these two sequences of moves:

```
x:(1,1) o:(2,1) x:(1,0) o:(2,0)
```

and

```
x:(1,0) o:(2,0) x:(1,1) o:(2,1)
```

The sequences are different, but they arrive at the same final state:

```
|   | x | o
------------
|   | x | o
```

Here is the root cause of the slowness: **when your program arrives at a repeated state for the second time, it evaluates the position exactly as if it's the first time that it has seen it**. This is wasteful: identical positions with three-move look-aheads will be evaluated four times; with four-move look-aheads, they would be evaluated eight times, and so on. This causes slowness proportional to `2^N`, where `N` is the depth of your look-ahead.

Fixing this requires an addition of a lookup table. Given a state of the game, this table would give you the score for you or for the opponent, if such score has been calculated before. Your recursive functions would build a position key, and try a lookup in the score table. If the answer is there, it would be returned immediately. Otherwise, your function would construct the answer, and store it at the position key. Next time the same position occurs through a different series of moves, the answer would be reused.

Comment: Thanks for response. Your answer was very useful. I tried to realize this method and results are perfect... almost. Performance increased in more than 10 times. But AI becomes a little stupid... Need I to store board state in this addition table?

Comment: @timer You are welcome! The state of the board is already stored implicitly in the table, because it's the lookup key. What you may need to store is the depth: if the additional table contains the result for a state obtained when the depth was lower than your current depth, you should proceed with calculations, and replace the entry with the results calculated with an improved depth. Otherwise, results calculated when you were almost out of depth will trump potentially better results calculated with more depth to go.

Comment: I will try to implement this. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning). It's possible that your game has as high branching factor, in which case you will want to avoid searching areas that won't affect the outcome.

You can also limit your search to a certain depth. Pick a depth that retrieves competent moves, but doesn't take too long.